# Why my program doesn't work after launch?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to add endless clouds, but my program doesn't work, what's wrong?

```py
class Cloud(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Cloud, self).__init__()
        self.image = clouds_jpg
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE1)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = random.randint(0, WIDTH)
        self.rect.centery = random.randint(HEIGHT - 550, HEIGHT)


    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(-2, 0)
        if self.rect.right <= 0:
            self.rect.left = screen.get_width() 

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
cloud = Cloud()
all_sprites.add(player, cloud)
...
elif event.type == ADDCLOUD:
            new_cloud = Cloud()
            cloud.add(new_cloud)
            all_sprites.add(new_cloud)
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\дом\My
> project\111.py", line 117, in 
> cloud.add(new_cloud)   File "C:\Users\дом\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py",
> line 133, in add
> self.add(*group) TypeError: add() argument after * must be an iterable, not Cloud

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cloud` is a [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite). You only can add a `pygame.sprite.Sprite` object toto a [`pygame.sprite_Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group):

```py
clouds = pygame.sprite.Group()
```

```py
elif event.type == ADDCLOUD:
    new_cloud = Cloud()
    
    # cloud.add(new_cloud)
    clouds.add(new_cloud)

    all_sprites.add(new_cloud)
```

Comment: clouds = pygame.sprite.Group()